# What need I do to retain the connection to my Azure DB?

Tags: azure, database-connection, ip-address, azure-sql-database, linqpad

I had been able to connect to my SQL DB via LINQPad, but today I get the dreaded red x mark on the connection, and the hint/tooltip tells me that the IP address attempting to connect is quad non grata.

I reckon perhaps that my IP address is dynamic, and the one originally set has been replaced by a new one. If I'm right about that, surely I don't have to create a new connection based on whatever my IP Address happens to be each time it changes...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure you need to configure the firewall to accept connections. If you get a new IP for your dev-machine you'll need to reconfigure the firewall. You don't need to change the connection string.

If you frequently get a new IP. Do something like [this](http://codemares.blogspot.se/2012/06/update-azure-db-firewall-rules-with.html) to automatically update the firewall.

Comment: Recent additions to the Powershell cmdlets for Azure allow for adding IP address to the acceptable list.  So you could run a script based on this cmdlet that would add your new IP address to the list.  Here's a blog with the details: http://michaelwasham.com/2011/09/27/updating-sql-azure-firewall-rules-with-windows-azure-powershell-cmdlets-2-0/.

Comment: But since my IP address apparently changed dynamically at random of its own accord, I don't see this as being very helpful - how am I to know when it's going to change, and to what?